# Why cannot see Ping Class in c#?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I'm making an application in Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows Phone 8.1, when I want to make a function to use Ping object, Visual Studio doesn't find this one, I search documentation at MSDN but I don't find something wrong because the examples uses the same way and tells is compatible to Windows Phone 8.1.

The using sentence:

```
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
```

and the declaration of a variable:

```
Ping somevar = new Ping();
```

I only see two clases at NetworkInformation: NetworkChange and NetworkInterface.

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you installed the Phone SDKs? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471. Also, consider upgrading to the Community edition http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs

Comment: Link that MSDN article you're referring to.

Comment: Did you check the references and make sure all of the required libraries are there?

Comment: Yes, I do @Tieson T.

Comment: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.110).aspx) @ChubosaurusSoftware

Comment: I think yes, i used `using System.Net.NetworkInformation;` that is neccesary to invoke the Ping class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the documentation for class [Ping on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.110).aspx). At the end in Version information and Platforms sections you will find the list of supported frameworks and platforms:

```
.NET Framework
Supported in: 4.5.3, 4, 3.5, 3.0, 2.0

.NET Framework Client Profile
Supported in: 4, 3.5 SP1

Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows 8, Windows Server 2012, Windows 7, 
Windows Vista SP2, Windows Server 2008 (Server Core Role not supported), 
Windows Server 2008 R2 (Server Core Role supported with SP1 or later; Itanium not supported)
```

This means that `Ping` class is not supported on Windows Phone

Answer (score 0):

Because I'm beginner in C#, I used a class that's not supported on Windows Store Apps, [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br230302.aspx). I'm very dissapointed because it have few classes with very basic features, that uses networking functions in WSA, and doesn't cover my needs. It is a pity. :(